# @Transactional rollbackFor scope

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, exception, transactions

I'm using `@Transactional` in my code and I'm created a custom exception to show error messages in specific format in UI.

```
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException
```

When this exception is encountered I still want to rollback my transactions, same as in case when any other exception occurs.

So to make it work, I writing below code:

```
// service method called from rest controller
public List<String> getMyData() { 
    
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList();
    try {
        businessMethod();
    } catch (MyCustomException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage);
        errors.add(e.getMessage)
    }
return errors.
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {MyCustomException.class, RuntimeException.class, Exception.class})
public String businessMethod() {
    // Business logic to get data that can throw MyCustomException
}
```

My questions are:

1. If I'm mentioning `MyCustomException.class` in `rollbackFor`, do I need to also mention `RuntimeException.class, Exception.class`. Or whatever is mentioned in `rollbackFor` gets appended along with default exceptions for which transaction is rolled-back.
2. Although I'm escaping the `MyCustomException` from `businessMethod()`, but I'm catching it on its calling method `getMyData()`. I'm assuming that the transaction will be rolled-back in case of exception, correct?

Comment: I think you are not using Transactional annotation properly in the given example. The correct way should be to call businessMethod on some spring bean and not directly.

Answer (score 1):

1. The transaction will be rolled back on any `RuntimeException`, so it is not necessary to declare your own `MyException.class` in `rollbackFor` section, since your `MyException` extends `RuntimeException`. If you declare `Exception.class` the rollback will be performed on any Exception. But in your case you do not need `rollbackFor` at all.
2. Yes, it is correct. Your transcation starts and ends in `businessMethod()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've doubts in pt.2. I dont think it will rollback.

Comment: Did you try it? The expected behavior should be that the transaction is rolled back in your case because you catch your exception out of @Transactional scope.